# Jasper property net.sf.jasperreports.governor.timeout is not working with Java 8

Tags: jasper-reports

We were using Jasper property to kill infinite loop of any report "net.sf.jasperreports.governor.timeout" and it was working fine with Java 7.

But after upgrading to Java 8, it seems stop working. We have to add "net.sf.jasperreports.governor.max.pages" property to stop infinite loop of any report creation.

Is it Java 8 problem or Jasper property changed?

Comment: Did you change the version of JR? What version of JR are you using?

Comment: It's 5.1.0, which we changed last year from 4.6.0

Comment: Did you set `net.sf.jasperreports.governor.timeout.enabled` property?

Comment: Yes I did. Is it possible that my page is generating but it's generating infinite times?

Comment: Same problem here, but with OpenJDK11 and JR 6.9.0. Funny thing is if I set the timeout value to 100 then it works fine and quickly (the report is never finished) but if I set it to 10000 (I think 10 seconds is a sensible value?) it does not work and the report consumes all of the server memory after much more than 10 seconds (something more like 10 agonising minutes).